# Why coordinates are not setted into the object?

Tags: angular, leaflet

I have an angular app using the leaflet library in which I want to click on the map and save the coordinates into a BD.

To do this, I have a map.component.ts where coordinates are taken and passed to the service.ts, but in the service.ts I receive an empty object.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FeaturesService } from '../../services/feature.service'
import { Vertex } from '../../models/vertex'

declare let L;

var lat;
var lng;
var coordinatesObj: Vertex;
var map;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _vertexService: FeaturesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    map = L.map('map').setView([40.4893538, -3.6827461], 13);


    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

  }


  getCoordinates() {
    map.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      lat = ev.latlng.lat;
      lng = ev.latlng.lng;

      coordinatesObj = {
        "lat": lat,
        "lng": lng
      };


    })
    this.sendCoords(coordinatesObj);
  }

  sendCoords(coordinatesObj) {

    this._vertexService.registerVertex(coordinatesObj).subscribe(

      response => {
        if (!response) {
          console.log('there is no response')
        } else {

          console.log(response)
        }
      },
      error => {
        let errorMessage = < any > error;
        if (errorMessage !== null) {
          let body = JSON.parse(error._body);
          console.log('error:' + body);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The variables lat and long are declarated outside the map.addEventListenerEvent so they could be reached in any method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCoordinates` function is wrong. You do not wait for an actual click event to be triggered and instead send an empty `coordinatesObj` to the `sendCoords` function.

Instead you should register for the click handler and send the coordinates only after the event handler has been called.

```
map.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  lat = ev.latlng.lat;
  lng = ev.latlng.lng;

  coordinatesObj = {
    "lat": lat,
    "lng": lng
  };

  // This part is important! Now the sendCoords will only be called after the use clicked on the map.
  this.sendCoords(coordinatesObj);
});
```

I would suggest to register for the click handler in your `ngOnInit` function. The `getCoordinates`  function might become obsolute but without seeing your HTML I cannot say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in trying to call the getCoordinates method which only registers the click listener and then sends an empty object to the sendCoords method.
Depending on the use case I'd rather shift the line `this.sendCoords(coordinatesObj)` into the `addEventListern` and always execute it after it has been clicked.

Sidenote: Imho it'd be better to leverage angular patterns and create a separate service for passing the coordinatesObj around instead of declaring a variable outside of the component.